# estimate Gamma from weighted data

Tags: r, gamma-distribution, weighted-data

I have weighted data (`Dist` = "Distance") that I expect to be in a Gamma distribution. There are about 28,000 observations that expand to a population of about 730,000.
I intend to use R to graph the data and estimate the parameters.  The data look like this:

```
SAMPN   Dist    LTWeight
100051  0.06    27.74877089
100052  0.41    55.49754179
100054  0.27    27.74877089
100064  0.24    47.56932153
100210  1.03    31.05218855
100067  0.16    11.89233038
100068  0.12    23.78466077
100232  2.12    65.75757576
100069  0.2     11.89233038
100076  0.28    71.3539823
100077  0.13    35.67699115
...
```

I can plot the histogram with `wtd.hist`, and using `wtd.mean` and `wtd.var` (and the method of moments?) I can assert one estimate of a Gamma distribution.  This does not give me much in the way of evaluating how good the fit is.

I'm looking for a maximum likelihood estimation, but I don't see one for a Gamma that takes weighted observations.  When I see (e.g. in `glm`) weights, it seems to me that weights in the `glm` package refers to weights applied to the curve fitting rather than expansion weights like mine.

How do I perform a maximum likelihood estimation of a gamma function to my weighted data?

Comment: Could you please explain what these weights *mean* and what distinction you are drawing between "applied to the fitted curve" and applied "to the base data"?

Comment: The weights expand the sampled passengers to the total passenger population.  Distance is haw far they walked.         As far as  "applied to the fitted curve" and applied "to the base data"        My uninformed reading of the documentation made me think that these were not expansion weights but some kind of weighting on the (shape and rate?) "things" being fitted.  If I understood more, I wouldn't be here asking questions :-)

Comment: I'm having trouble with the concept of non-integral weights here, given that there cannot be non-integral numbers of passengers.  Exactly how are these weights determined?  Would they reflect inclusion probabilities, frequencies, importance, or something else?

Comment: from glm documentation:weights 
the working weights, that is the weights in the final iteration of the IWLS fit.

Comment: Well, that is interesting because it's totally unexpected and ought to have a profound effect on how one goes about estimation.  Please edit your post to explain that these come from an IWLS fit (presumably they're residuals). It seems like a conceptual contradiction to try to perform such a fit and then apply MLE, but maybe someone can make sense of it.

Comment: Each surveyed passenger represents some total.  If I got 5 survey returns form a subset of passengers totaling 273, that component of weight would be 54.6.  If that subset of the day was 273 of a daily total of 497, a further weight of 1.82 would be applied.

Comment: That further complicates things, because it sounds like your weights are some kind of product of completely different factors based on completely different considerations.  Unless you disclose the details, you should expect that any answer could be awfully wrong because it would have to be based on implicit guesses about what you have done.

Comment: I posted the documentation of glm, which I have not used.  My weights come from a survey effort, I posted the documentation to show, as requested, that the weights used in glm were not expansion weights on data but something in the estimation process.

Comment: Yes, the weights are complicated as they expand the survey returns to the  total linked person trips (not total boardings) using the system.  A great deal of care went into creating them, and for "normal" analysis they work fine.      We wish to test if one of the variables does indeed fit a gamma distribution as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62420/discussion-between-robert-farley-and-whuber).